# how can i check the same values in an array?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to check the same `int` values in an array!
For example,

```
int a1 = arc4random()%9 +1;
int a2 = arc4random()%9 +1;
int a3 = arc4random()%9 +1;
int a4 = arc4random()%9 +1;
int a5 = arc4random()%9 +1;
int array[5] ={a1,a2,a3,a4,a5};
```

now! there is a problem! 
some int values in array! so how can i check the same value in an array?
To be specific,

```
a[0] = {1}
a[1] = {3}
a[2] = {6}
a[3] = {3}
a[4] = {3}
```

if arch4random make that values. how can i check the same values?
(a[2] = a[3] = a[4])?

Comment: You want to keep only unique values?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < lenarray; i++) {
  for (int j = i; j < lenarray; j++) {
    if (array[i] == array[j]) {
      printf("Same value\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Just use for loops. E.g. to find duplicates of `array[0]` you might do:

```
int x = array[0];
int repetitions = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int y = array[i];
    if (x == y) {
        repetitions++;
    }
} 

printf("array[0] = %i and occurrs %i times.",x, repetitions+1);
```